# Permutations of a limited set size in PHP

Tags: php

I have letters, from 'a' to 'v' (22 char input). I would like a result of, all possible sets of those numbers in a set size of 3.

I would like to see the solution made in PHP that could print out the result. I do not know the formula to calculate how many permutations that will be?

$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v");

Example sets:

```
a-a-a
a-a-b ..
a-b-c
a-c-b
b-a-c
b-c-a
c-a-b
c-b-a
a-b-d
and so on... v-v-v
```

Hoping it is easy to modify to result a set size of 2 as well.

```
a-a
a-b
b-a
a-c
and so on... v-v
```

Thanks So Much ^^,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
    for($i = 'a' ; $i<='v';++$i)
        for($j = 'a' ; $j<='v';++$j)  
            for($k = 'a' ; $k<='v';++$k)
                {echo $i.'-'.$j.'-'.$k;
                echo '<br>';
            }

    ?>
```

this will do :)

Comment: So when you do ++$i it adds to the letter? That's Cool!